# How to integrate function in R with unknown upper or lower limit

Tags: r

I'm quite unfamiliar with R and I tried find answer to my question by open sources, but I couldn't. So here it is:

So I have pd function and I want to find cdf from it. It's very simple and I need only to integrate pd function with lower limit as 1 and upper limit as "x". I tried to do it by R, but an error occured when I attempted to do it with code bellow:

```
 f <- function(x) ((3*x^2)/511)
 integrate(f, lower = 1, upper = "x")
```

Error:

> Error in integrate(f, lower = 1, upper = "x") :
> the integral is probably divergent

And the right answer for cdf is (3*(x^3/3 = 1/3))/511. Is it even possible to integrate with unknown limit in R and get output like the right answer(use the R as a calculator :D)?

Comment: R itself does not do symbolic math (like programs such as Mathematica or Matlab). You could use a package like [Ryacas](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Ryacas). But it's probably easier to do that with other tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think that @MrFlick is right; there are tools that are better suited for advanced math in this form. However, you can do it in R.

```
library(Ryacas)
as_r(yac_str("Integrate(x, 1, x) (3*x^2)/511"))
# expression(x^3/511 - 1/511)
```

The answer, which you provided, calculated by R: [image: x^3 - 1 / 511]